# Getting rid of all the rounded corners in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I love Twitter Bootstrap 2.0 - I love how it's such a complete library... but I want to make a global modification for a very boxy-not-round site, which is to get rid of all the rounded corners in Bootstrap...

That's a lot of CSS to chug through. Is there a global switch, or what would be the best way to find and replace all the rounded's?

Comment: Are you looking to remove all or just some rounded corners?

Comment: If you can't modify what you currently have in place, I created a mod file that has all border-radii set to 0: http://mkamyszek.tumblr.com/post/61791361233/remove-all-border-radius-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: ina, did my answer worked out for you? would you mark it as correct?

Answer (score 355, accepted):

I set all element's border-radius to "0" like this:

```
* {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

As I'm sure I don't want to overwrite this later I just use !important.

If you are not compiling your less files just do:

```
* {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
          border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

In bootstrap 3 if you are compiling it you can now set radius in the variables.less file:

```
@border-radius-base:        0px;
@border-radius-large:       0px;
@border-radius-small:       0px;
```

In bootstrap 4 if you are compiling it you can disable radius alltogether in the `_custom.scss` file:

```
$enable-rounded:   false;
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution if you are trying to customize bootstrap without touching the core files.  Great answer!

Comment: Heck yeah, quick n dirty!

Comment: I had used this
    ```* {
      -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
         -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
          border-radius: 0 !important;
    }```
And it is working perfectly for Bootstrap 3.2. Thanx for the fix man!

Comment: This solution doesn't work for bootstrap styled <select> inputs. Probably due to the use of `-webkit-appearance: menulist`.

Comment: This a probably a good solution, but not the best. This will generate large number of redundant CSS for each element unnecessarily. I think this is one of the best solution provided by @ymakux. You can try this

Comment: @John did you find a solution to reset the border-radius for select inputs?

Comment: @xgrioux, for `<select>` specifically I couldn't find a perfect solution. if you apply `-webkit-border-radius:0 !important` and `-webkit-appearance:none !important` you get pretty close, but you lose the dropdown arrows. you would need to manually add in an arrow image.

Comment: super easy solution!

Comment: `$enable-rounded:   false;` also applies to bootstrap 5 sass FYI

Answer (score 25):

Download the source `.less` files and make the `.border-radius()` mixin blank.

Comment: This is the perhaps the best solution as far as efficiency with mastering Bootstrap CSS processing.

Answer (score 21):

If you are using Bootstrap version < 3...

With sass/scss

```
$baseBorderRadius: 0;
```

With less

```
@baseBorderRadius: 0;
```

You will need to set this variable *before* importing the bootstrap. This will affect all wells and navbars.

**Update**

If you are using Bootstrap 3 *baseBorderRadius* should be *border-radius-base*

Answer (score 19):

If you want to avoid recompiling the all thing, just add `.btn {border-radius: 0;}` to your CSS.

Comment: It will impact only on buttons and wherever you have added `.btn`

Answer (score 18):

```
code,
kbd,
pre,
.img-rounded,
.img-thumbnail,
.img-circle,
.form-control,
.btn,
.btn-link,
.dropdown-menu,
.list-group-item,
.input-group-addon,
.input-group-btn,
.nav-tabs a,
.nav-pills a,
.navbar,
.navbar-toggle,
.icon-bar,
.breadcrumb,
.pagination,
.pager *,
.label,
.badge,
.jumbotron,
.thumbnail,
.alert,
.progress,
.panel,
.well,
.modal-content,
.tooltip-inner,
.popover,
.popover-title,
.carousel-indicators li {
    border-radius:0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Bootstrap has it's own classes for borders including `.rounded-0` to get rid of rounded corners on any element including `buttons`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/borders/#border-radius

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a class="btn btn-primary">Regular Rounded Corners</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill">Pill Corners</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary rounded-0">Square Corners</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

This question is pretty old however it is highly visible on search engines even in **Bootstrap 4** related searches. I think it worths to add an answer for disabling the rounded corners, BS4 way.

In the `_variables.scss` there are several global modifiers exists to quickly change the stuff such as enabling or disabling flex gird system, rounded corners, gradients etc. :

```
$enable-flex:          false !default;
$enable-rounded:       true !default; // <-- This one
$enable-shadows:       false !default;
$enable-gradients:     false !default;
$enable-transitions:   false !default;
```

Rounded corners are `enabled` by default.

If you prefer compiling the Bootstrap 4 using Sass and your very own `_custom.scss` like me (or using official customizer), overriding the related variable is enough:

```
$enable-rounded : false
```

Comment: you rock ;) This should be the accepted answer once Bootstrap 4 goes viral... sorry, public. It's well hidden down here for those already using it in alpha.

Answer (score 6):

With SASS Bootstrap - if you are compiling Bootstrap yourself - you can set all border radius (or more specific) simply to zero:

```
$border-radius:               0;
$border-radius-lg:            0;
$border-radius-sm:            0;
```

Comment: Exactly. Put these declarations before e.g. `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` and bootstrap will not override them, since they're declared with the `!default` keyword in bootstrap-source.

Answer (score 5):

```
.btn {
  border-radius:                    0px;
  -webkit-border-radius:            0px;
  -moz-border-radius:               0px;
}
```

Or define a mixin and include it wherever you want an unrounded button.

```
@mixin btn-round-none {
  border-radius:                    0px;
  -webkit-border-radius:            0px;
  -moz-border-radius:               0px;
}

.btn.btn_1 {
@inlude btn-round-none
}
```

Comment: I usually keep 'px' so that if I have to change the value I don't have to type 'px' again.

Comment: but the extra bytes of data

Answer (score 5):

When using Bootstrap >= `3.0` source files (`SASS` or `LESS`) you don't have to get rid of the rounded corners on everything if there is just one element that is bugging you, for example, to just get rid of the rounded corners on the navbar, use:

#### With SCSS:

```
$navbar-border-radius: 0;
```

#### With LESS:

```
@navbar-border-radius: 0;
```

However, if you do want to get rid of the rounded corners on everything, you can do what @adamwong246 mentioned and use:

```
$baseBorderRadius: 0;
@baseBorderRadius: 0;
```

Those two settings are the "root" settings from which the other settings like `navbar-border-radius` will inherit from unless other values are specified.

For a list all variables check out the [variables.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less) or [variables.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss)

Answer (score 4):

The code posted above by @BrunoS did not work for me,

```
* {
  .border-radius(0) !important;
}
```

what i used was

```
* {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

I hope this helps someone

Comment: @brunos was using `LESS`

Answer (score 4):

There is a very easy way to customize Bootstrap:

1. Just go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
2. Find all "radius" and modify them as you wish.
3. Click "Compile and Download" and enjoy your own version of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using bootstrap you can just use the bootstrap class="rounded-0" to make the border with the sharp edges with no rounded corners
`<button class="btn btn-info rounded-0"">Generate</button></span>`

Comment: which version of bootstrap

Comment: This I tried in Bootsrap 4 and 'rounded-0' removes the rounded corner on an input box

Answer (score 2):

Or you could add this to the html of the element you want to remove the border radius from (this way you wouldn't be removing it from all buttons / elements):

```
style="border-radius:0px; -webkit-border-radius:0px; -moz-border-radius:0px;"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to have a look at [FlatStrap](http://www.flatstrap.org/). It provides a Metro-Style replacement for the Bootstrap CSS without rounded corners, gradients and drop shadows.

Comment: Problem with Flatstrap is that they don't have SCSS support for v3 yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I have create another css file and add the following code 
Not all element are included

```
/* Flatten das boostrap */
.well, .navbar-inner, .popover, .btn, .tooltip, input, select, textarea, pre, .progress, .modal, .add-on, .alert, .table-bordered, .nav>.active>a, .dropdown-menu, .tooltip-inner, .badge, .label, .img-polaroid, .panel {
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```