# How to set border radius to 0 using ng2-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm trying to remove all border-radius globally in bootstrap 3. I have looked at other threads [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742166/getting-rid-of-all-the-rounded-corners-in-twitter-bootstrap), but I doesn't remove border radius when: 
@media (min-width: 768px). I have gone into the variable.less and changed:

```
@border-radius-base:        0px;
@border-radius-large:       0px;
@border-radius-small:       0px;
```

However it still isn't working, what am I missing?

Comment: did you use less or scss in your app?

Comment: the variable.less only work if you using less, it won't work if you using css only